# symfony: getting error /usr/local/bin/: Permission denied in assetic:dump

Tags: symfony, less, assetic, linux-mint, symfony-3.2

My assetic configuration is:

```
assetic:
debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller: false
filters:
    less:
     node: /usr/local/bin/
     node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
     apply_to: '\.less$'
```

when I run command `bin/console assetic:dump` then I am getting below error:

`[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]

  An error occurred while running:

  '/usr/local/bin/' '/tmp/assetic_lessgyMQtZ'

  Error Output:

  sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/: Permission denied`

Comment: try your command with sudo

Comment: I tried but its not working